# Spring app run work in intellij, but java -jar doesnt

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I create restfull spring app with mySQL database. MyApp running well in Intellij, i build the jar with build artifacts in intellij. When i run the jar (java -jar) i got error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]:

here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestApp?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.example
    MyApp
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    jar

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can anyone help?Thank you

Comment: How you have built a jar? Mvn build command?

Comment: @sankar build artifacts in intellij

Comment: "mvn clean build" try this on your terminal window. it will build a jar with dependencies and use that jar

Comment: mvn package is right command for spring boot try that on your terminal

Comment: @sankar build fail, "cant find package" from external jar (i put them in lib directory)

Comment: you dont need to put that on lib usually mvn does that for you. It will pick from global repositories. Can you post the command that you have used and full log.

Comment: have you tried mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: @MehdiBenmesssaoud i have tried. It run well

Comment: @sankar i have delete all jar in lib, and redownload from global repo. The result is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jar running well, after i choose to manual config Database connection

add in Application class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

and then
create

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:app.datasource.properties" })
class DatabaseConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("app.datasource.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("app.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("app.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("app.datasource.password"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

i don't know why my jar can't get autoconfiguration from spring, maybe someone can explain in comments below

Answer (score 0):

That would suggest you don't have all you dependencies in you jar. Are you running correct jar - you might have more than one - one with app and one from boot in a different dir. Would be good to see a command you use to build as well.